# Realm multi-process best practice

Tags: android, realm

I have an app that have two processes, one for the ui and one for a service. Currently, when a change is made on the ui, i send the object through a bundle to the service in the other process. Currently, it looks too hard to do this way, parcelling and unparcelling data. Will like to know if its safe to save those changes to realm on the ui process and then notify the other process (service) of the change, fetching the data  from realm there ?.

Comment: @pskink, its a music player app. I saw the recommended way to do it was using different processes.

Comment: https://medium.com/@rotxed/going-multiprocess-on-android-52975ed8863c

Comment: Currently ? No, the app works fine across processes. My issue is finding the database that works well across processes. Not sure multiprocess is officially supported in realm. Thanks

Comment: The meduim post clearly explained what. Do you think multiprocess is not worth the extra stress ?. Thanks

Comment: Musixmatch, jamsplayer, jockey player and several other popular music app do follow

Comment: Multi-process migrations can still cause problems with Realm according to https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/1300 but notifications across processes should work since 2.x (although 3.x is more stable)

Comment: The underlying storage engine is safe to use across processes, so is the notifications. The only thing missing right now is making sure that schema initialization and changes to the schema behave correctly. If you can coordinate opening the Realm for the first time in both processes (since that will validate and run migrations), then yes, it will be process safe. But the general recommendation is still to wait for official support.

Comment: @ChristianMelchior, thanks. By schema changes, do you mean changes to the realm object model ?. Do you mean if i open a realm instance at the beginning of each process by calling Realm.getDefaultInstance(), that every thing will be fine. Have been waiting since 2016 for full multi-process, hope it gets a higher priority at realm. Thanks

Comment: When opening a Realm file for the first time, we will create the required tables in the underlying core + create some in-memory data structures representing the schema. This process has race conditions across processes. So you need to make sure that the first call to `getInstance()` has completed in one process before calling it in another process. Otherwise, you risk all sorts of schema errors (none that will corrupt the Realm file though).

Comment: @ChristianMelchior, Thanks so much. This is what i intend to do: When the first process is started, I will init realm and getInstance in my Application class. Then in my first activity i will start the second process which will also init realm and getInstance since processes share the same Application class. Also since the Application class onCreate method will be called before any activity is started, i believe realm will be ready before the second process is started in an activity. This should be safe ?

Comment: Yes, but we don't support that scenario officially yet, so it hasn't been fully tested and I might be forgetting some details.

Comment: Okay, the approach am taking is to do all realm db stuff on the main process. If there is any change or a need to pass values, i send it to the background process using intents. Have removed all realm access in the service. This should work fine ? Accessing realm from only one of the processes ?